# How to refresh a ListViewBuilder when to click on a butotn?

Tags: flutter

I want to filter a listview by id or author using provider after i click on RaisedButton, but nothing seems to happen, that's what id did:

The refreshed button

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final todo_provider = Provider.of<TodoProvider>(context);
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Filter me'),
            onPressed: () {

              todo_provider.settNewss('John Biggs');
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

The result in ListView

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final todo_provider = Provider.of<TodoProvider>(context);

    // TODO: implement build
    return Container(
      child: FutureBuilder<News>(
        future: _future,
        initialData: todo_provider.getnews,
        builder: (context, snapshot) =>
            snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.none ||
                    snapshot.data == null
                ? CircularProgressIndicator()
                : Container(
                    height: 500.0,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: snapshot.data.articles.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) => Text(
                        snapshot.data.articles[index].author.toString(),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution, is to update the future value on FutureBuilder:

OLD:

```
onPressed: () {
  todo_provider.settNewss('John Biggs');
}
```

NEW:

```
onPressed: () {
  _future = usersProvider.fetchUsers('John Biggs');
}
```

OR:

```
 onPressed: () {
     _future = Provider.of<TodoProvider>(context, listen: false)
                                    .fetchUsers('John Biggs');
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

try to wrap your onPressed function by a setState

```
  onPressed: () {
          setState() {
           todo_provider.settNewss('John Biggs');
          }
        },
```

Comment: Thank you for your replay, it's not the right way to solve the issue because i am using provider which mean that i have to avoid setState(){}

Comment: i didn't notice that sorry

Answer (score 0):

When using provider, to update data back to your Consumer you have to use

```
notifyListener();
```

Thus, under your settNewss() method, you probably need to use notifyListener() in the end to update the Consumer who are listening to this.

Tips: If you dont want to listen to the Provider on certain screens, you can use

```
final todo_provider = Provider.of<TodoProvider>(context, listen: false);
```

By doing this, your notifyListener() will not notify every widget that need this data.

Comment: Thank you, but i already added notifyListener(); when i call settNewss() method